# Betas from precision matrix?

Tags: covariance, lasso, regularization, matrix

This is really 2 questions.

1. I would like to do a linear multi-regression on a large quantity of data, so large that I cannot really store it (it’s about 1e10 observations across 2500 features). Hence I can only use the covariance matrix and the means for this (which I got after slicing the data). **Is there a way to do a Lasso regularisation directly from the means and the covariance matrix?**
2. From what I understand the regularisation has to be done on the precision matrix (the inverse of the covariance matrix). **How do you derive the regression coefficients from the precision matrix?**

*Bonus question: what’s the best Python package to do this?*